# How to fix Wordpress images not showing up in local hosted XAMPP server?

Tags: theme-development, images, xampp

I have recently been trying to establish a working method of developing Wordpress sites locally by making use of an XAMPP server. The issue is that any images that I attempt to use refuse to show up when I load the page in a browser. I'm using the 
    `<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/library/images/name_of_the_svg_image`
file path, and when you right click and find them in the browser inspector HTML them shows the source as: 
`C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\wp/wp-content/themes/**Site name**/library/images/name_of_the_svg_image`
Which, when I copy and paste it into the browser, shows the image properly. Is there something obvious that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

`get_template_directory()` Retrieves the absolute path to the directory of the current theme, without the trailing slash.

You should use  `get_template_directory_uri();`  for showing correct image path on site.

`echo get_template_directory();?>/library/images/name_of_the_svg_image`  will work in your case.

[Details here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

Answer (score 0):

use `bloginfo('template_url')`

`<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/library/images/name_of_the_svg_image`

you need a url... not directory...

more on [bloginfo here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)